# Show MHTML content with CSS-styled negative margin in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, mhtml

My application receives MHTML content from external service and displays it.
Some elements in MHTML are styled via CSS and have negative margin, like this one:

```
<style type="text/css">
      .csAE6E0F4D{margin-left:-49.9pt}
</style>
```

`WebBrowser`, obviously, starts to render these elements outside of client area boundaries, and elements are partially visible to user.

Is there any way to set document margin or scroll document to show elements entirely? I can't change external service easily.